# Downloading a file using GridFS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs

I managed to upload a file to my mongoDB database, like this:

```
uploadFile(file, uid) {
    var grid = require('gridfs-stream');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var fs = require('fs');

    mongoose.connect(config.db, {useNewUrlParser: true},).catch(e => console.log(e));
    var conn = mongoose.connection;
    grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
    const gfs = grid(conn.db);
    const writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: file.filename,
    });
    fs.createReadStream(file.path).pipe(writeStream);
    writeStream.on('close', file => {
        const {_id} = file;
        console.log(`${_id} written to the db`);
        return Account.findByIdAndUpdate(uid, {'employer.logo': _id}).then(r => console.log(r)).catch(e => console.log(e));
    });
}
```

So this resulted in this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bc9d28270e5375dfbfe17fd"
    },
    "employer": {

        "logo": "5bd72702d5dfad7f0f9f8c08",
    },
}
```

It also created a `fs.files` and `fs.chunks` documents

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bd72702d5dfad7f0f9f8c08"
    },
    "filename": "6d6104894af7d98779430a7457ce3e4e",
    "contentType": "binary/octet-stream",
    "length": 17283,
    "chunkSize": 261120,
    "uploadDate": {
        "$date": "2018-10-29T14:09:18.725Z"
    },
    "aliases": null,
    "metadata": null,
    "md5": "2e6afedd69510b1b526f1015c47065e2"
}
```

And this in the `fs.chunks`

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bd72702d5dfad7f0f9f8c09"
    },
    "files_id": {
        "$oid": "5bd72702d5dfad7f0f9f8c08"
    },
    "n": 0,
    "data": "<Binary Data>"
}
```

So I think it's all good here. But now I cannot figure out how to read it. This is what I have so far.

```
downloadFile: async id => {
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.file.find(id).then(r => console.log(r)).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

I saw something like this on the internet but cannot find it now. Any idea what's wrong with this?

Comment: Hi, is using mongoose module important for your use-case?

Comment: I am reading the id of the file using mongoose. I don't really care how I get the image itself back

Comment: There are quite some examples using mongodb, but am finding it difficult to find articles on mongoose-gridfs. Using mongodb, you could try the sample given here: https://thecodebarbarian.com/mongodb-gridfs-stream